# Moving file between buckets on same amazon account

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm having some issues moving files on amazon s3 in a lambda trigger.
I am able to do the `s3.getObject` but i think my issue is where im doing the `s3.putObject`

```
var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
var srcKey = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
var s3params = {Bucket: srcBucket, Key: srcKey};

s3.getObject(s3params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log("Loaded " + data.ContentLength + " bytes"); // successful response

    var destinationpath = destinationbucket + '/moved_files/';
    console.log("Destination: " +destinationpath);

    var destiniation_name = destinationpath + str.split("/")[3];
    console.log(destiniation_name);
    var upparams = {Bucket: destinationbucket, Key: destiniation_name,ContentType: data.ContentType, Body: data.Stream};
    s3.putObject(upparams,function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log("upload response " +data); // successful response
        context.succeed('exit');
    });
});
```

Comment: If you're just doing a copy from one bucket to another without making any changes to the contents of the file you can do that directly with the `copyObject` method. Otherwise, show your error messages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44685801/304371

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are only moving files between buckets you can simply use [`S3.copyObject`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property):

```
var params = {
  CopySource: srcBucket + '/' + srcKey,
  Bucket: dstBucket,
  Key: dstKey
};

s3.copyObject(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

This will "move" the file internally in S3 which will be way faster than downloading and uploading it. Also you only have to pay a `PUT` request and nothing for the data transfer.

Comment: Will this delete the old object in CopySource or do you still have to do that?

Comment: copyObject doesn't 'move' the file, it copies it.
From the S3 documentation: "Creates a copy of an object that is already stored in Amazon S3."

Move is a user level operation that requires 2 steps:
1. copyObject    (source -> target)
2. deleteObject  (source)