# node.js renaming s3 object via aws-sdk module

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

Is it possible to rename an object on s3 via [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk)? I couldn't find a method for that, maybe there is a provisionary solution ...

Comment: Unless they have changed, I don't think you can rename objects on S3. You would copy it to an object with a new name and delete the original object.

Comment: Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/roparz/e9dedb2b8d421d75b989

Comment: @ barry-johnson : I hope thats not the case

Comment: @ jarmod : I knew that repo before, but I dont want to delete or copy the object

Comment: It is the case; you will need to copy and delete.

Comment: alright, you can answer the question

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I will answer I guess since no one has - this one should work

```
// create a new s3 object
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var BUCKET_NAME = 'your-bucket-name';
var OLD_KEY = '/original-file.js';
var NEW_KEY = '/new-file.js';

// Copy the object to a new location
s3.copyObject({
  Bucket: BUCKET_NAME, 
  CopySource: `${BUCKET_NAME}${OLD_KEY}`, 
  Key: NEW_KEY
 })
  .promise()
  .then(() => 
    // Delete the old object
    s3.deleteObject({
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME, 
      Key: OLD_KEY
    }).promise()
   )
  // Error handling is left up to reader
  .catch((e) => console.error(e))
```

Comment: try to rename file "file+sign.txt" to "filewithoutplus.txt" -> the error: key not exist will appears.. AWS have problems with plus sign in CopySource. Maybe copyObject is not the right method for file rename ?

Answer (score 5):

This is just a flow on from @nf071590 answer. Which is awesome.

Below, gets the entire list of a bucket and then changes the image name of every image that isn't `.jpg` to `.jpg`

Hope this helps someone. :)

```
const start = new Date()
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const state = {}

AWS.config.update({ region: 'ADD_REGION_HERE' })

try {
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();

    var BUCKET_NAME = 'ADD_BUCKET_NAME_HERE';

    var params = {
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      MaxKeys: 1000
    };
    s3.listObjects(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      } else {
        console.log(data);
        data.Contents.forEach(image => {

          var OLD_KEY = image.Key
          var NEW_KEY = ''
          // split key
          var keyArray = image.Key.split('.')
          var keyArrayLength = keyArray.length
          console.log(keyArrayLength);
          var ext = keyArray[keyArrayLength - 1]
          // console.log(ext);
          if(ext != 'jpg') {
            console.log('Change this ext FROM: ', OLD_KEY)
            ext = 'jpg'
            if (keyArrayLength == 2) {
              NEW_KEY = `${keyArray[0]}.${ext}`
            } else if (keyArrayLength == 3) {
              NEW_KEY = `${keyArray[0]}.${keyArray[1]}.${ext}`
            } else if (keyArrayLength == 4) {
              NEW_KEY = `${keyArray[0]}.${keyArray[1]}.${keyArray[2]}.${ext}`
            }
            console.log('TO:: ', NEW_KEY);
            // Copy the object to a new location
            try {
              s3.copyObject({
                Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
                CopySource: `${BUCKET_NAME}/${OLD_KEY}`,
                Key: NEW_KEY
              }).promise()
                .then((response) => {
                  console.log('Seemed to have worked??');
                  console.log(response);
                  // Delete the old object
                  s3.deleteObject({
                    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
                    Key: OLD_KEY
                  }).promise()
                })
                // Error handling is left up to reader
                .catch((e) => console.error(e))
            } catch (error) {
              console.log('error::', error);
            }
          }
        });
      } 
    });
} catch (err) {
  const end = new Date() - start
  let seconds = end / 1000
  state.seconds = seconds
  state.error = err
  state.status = "error"
  state.message = err.message
  console.log(err)
  console.log(state);
  return
}
```